# Channel slice of integers

Tags: go

I want to create a slice that is a channel and contains integers.

```
test := make(chan []int)
test <- 5
```

This is the way I initialized it but I have no idea how to now pass a value since for slices we would use append but for channels we send data using <-

I have tried with both just <- and append and both combined like below and can't get it to work

```
test <- append(test, 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a channel of `[]int` but are trying to send it an `int`. You have to send it a slice of ints and then have the receiver use that slice.

A working example is here: https://play.golang.org/p/TmcUKU8G-1

Notice that I'm appending the 4 to the `things` slice and not the channel itself

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan []int)

    things := []int{1, 2, 3}

    go func() {
        c <- things
    }()

    for _, i := range <-c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

    go func() {
        c <- append(things, 4)
    }()

    for _, i := range <-c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called

> buffered channel

the right syntaxis is

```
test := make(chan int, 5)    
test <- 1
test <- 2
```

Golang tour has an example:

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3

Comment: So this is a channel of ints, but what if I want the size to be dynamic?

Comment: Go does not support dynamically-sized channels.